# Maven Dependency - NoSuchMethodError on org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Properties

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jpa, intellij-idea

I'm following [this blogpost](http://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa#overview) to set up the Hibernate Persistence layer.

My current pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>projectname</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>selfserve.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Properties;
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:124)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:890)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
... 21 more
```

It looks like some of my dependencies conflict with one another, but I'm really not sure which one. Nothing online indicates any conflicts.

Any help or direction would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class - org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor - is resolved from dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And this class doesn't contain the getProperties() method. Please take a look at the source code.

Get rid of this dependency. Then your class will be resolved from the dependency - hibernate-core: 5.0.12.Final and org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor class present in this jar contains the getProperties() method.

[image]

Please let us know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Awesome! That fixed it. Now I'll know to check the dependency tree. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for letting us know!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using EhCache. Apparently the EhCache dependency depends on a different version of `hibernate-core`, causing the conflict. Changing it back to a corresponding version solved the problem:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-ehcache', version: '5.0.12.Final'
```

Given that `hibernate-core` version `5.0.12` is the version that is depended on by `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` of course (which it is!).

Answer (score 0):

Only use `hibernate 5.2`
use `hibernate-core:5.2.x`.Final and exclude `hibernate-entitymanager` as it is deprecated.